# What is the probability of a number of nodes finding another node in the IPv4 address space?

Tags: probability

So the IPv4 address space is comprised of 4,294,967,296 unique IP addresses. Say a number of nodes scan the address space, randomly choosing IP addresses to find other nodes in the address space. What is the probability of x number of nodes, randomly scanning IP addresses, finding another node? Assume all nodes are port forwarded and can accept incoming connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At each time unit $t$, each of the $x$ nodes move to a different address. Let's consider the case in which every node is assigned a different address Let $N = 4294967296$. There are $N$ choices for the first node, $N - 1$ for the second node, all the way down to $N - x + 1$ choices for the $x^{\text{th}}$ node. There are $N^{x}$ total ways to assign the nodes the addresses. Taking a complement, we find that our answer is given by

$$1 - \prod_{k=1}^{x} \frac{N - k + 1}{N^{x}} $$

Comment: Excuse my lack of mathematics but what does the Roman numeral that looks like two 'I's mean? Also what does k represent?

Comment: The $\prod$ is a product symbol, and the $k$ is a dummy variable used in the product. If you've ever seen the summation symbol (e.g. $\sum_{i=1}^{3} i = 1 + 2 + 3$), then you can think of the $\prod$ as the same thing, except we're taking a product. So $\prod_{k=1}^{x} k = 1 \times 2 \times 3 \times \cdots \times x$

Comment: I thought it had to do with the summation symbol. Such neat math, thank you.